# Have a furnace, compressor ok, can I install a heat pump?

Tags: hvac

Every contractor you talk to says that you cannot replace one without the other. My compressor is a 16 SEER Carrier and it's like 6 years old. I should not have gotten a gas furnace, should have gotten a heat pump system as I have solar. My question is can I just get rid of the gas furnace myself and install a heat pump? talked to 2 or 3 contractors and they all say no you have to replace the compressor at the same time.

Comment: The compressor is part of the AC condenser, which basically is the heatpump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While similar in appearance, there is considerable difference between an AC outside compressor and a Heat Pump outside compressor.  The Heat Pump unit requires extra plumbing and control components to reverse the operation and produce heat for the air handler vs. cold.  These parts are not present in an AC compressor since they would add cost without any added benefit to the purchaser.

So the people telling you that you must replace everything are exactly correct.

I'm assuming that your PV installation has been sized according to your projected electrical consumption.  In that case, you'll very likely be getting the maximum benefit from solar as it is.  If you add the additional load of heating then chances are that the PV capacity is not enough and you will be paying more for your heating bill as in almost all locations gas heating is significantly less expensive than electric heating.  That makes the economics of heating with solar much more difficult.  In other words, it doesn't make good financial sense to replace gas with solar.

Comment: Are you confusing solar pv with solar thermal or have you considered solar thermal in your analysis re solar & gas? I know of two buildings where the only source of heat is the sun... no gas, electric, fuel etc those are nice heating bills...

Comment: Thanks you know I think I knew this. I saw a really good explanation of how AC works where are they basically said it would just be reversing the system  Part of the reason I ask this question is I have two units they both have the AC one actually has a compressor with a heat pump the other one as I said has a gas furnace. When I replace that one I will for sure get Electric so I have no more gas requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If the solar is correctly designed then the call for backup from the furnace should be minimal. Why change to a heat pump? The capital cost is not likely to get paid off...

Why not consider reducing the load: look at the insulation levels and quality of the building ie air leaks etc.

Comment: I’m trying to get gas off my property and my solar system is producing way more energy than I’m using.

Comment: In that case you should do a financial analysis of the cost of a heat pump system vs. just selling the excess solar power back to the power company.  I'm assuming that in your location they don't do "net metering" so you are selling back to them at wholesale.  That's the thing with solar and other alternative energy installations, they don't always make good economic sense but before you spend money, run the numbers.

Comment: I unfortunately have DWP as my utility. They do not reimburse. They issue credits, and despite a lot of effort attempting to understand it, even those credits are not documented, nor can be fully understood. I am getting gas off my property. I am not sure why I have to keep saying that. I am generating enough electricity now to handle the tiny amount of heating I need living in Los Angeles. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob perhaps because you did not say that in your question... you should update your question with all the drops of info you have scattered in your comments.